# Maintaining scroll position as images load

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a list of chat messages on - some text, some images.

When the page loads, it scrolls to the bottom (that's where the latest message is)

```
$(cardBody).scrollTop($(cardBody)[0].scrollHeight);
```

If any of the messages are images, then then load and the screen grows but the user remains at same scrollHeight, and the messages disappear off the bottom of the screen

I can solve this by waiting for the page to fully load before calling scrollTop, however if a message is then dynamically added I'm not currently aware of a way to scroll to the bottom, and then "re-scroll" to the bottom one any images have loaded.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `if a message is then dynamically added I'm not currently aware of a way to scroll to the bottom` When that happens invoke the line of code again. Exactly how you do that depends on how the messages are added. As it's a chat system I'd hope there's a socket event you listen for, so it can just be put in to that

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `DOMSubtreeModified` event to get triggered when the messages dive updated.

```
$(cardBody).bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
   $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
});
```